# Software to recover data from an Android device that will not boot

Tags: phone, data-recovery, tablet

Is there any software, for any operating system, that allows you to recover data from an Android device that will not boot?  The device will turn on, but will not get past the initial boot screen.  It will not even boot into recovery.

Obviously, the data is not on removable storage.

Searching for such software yields plenty of results, 99% of which are likely scams or malware.

Recommendations for gratis software and commercial software are both welcome.

Comment: Consider asking for "how to recover…" at Android.SE (um, check first that such question doesn't already exist – I vaguely remember we've had a couple of those). My first comments there then would be: Can you boot into recovery at least? Is the device seen by ADB (`adb devices` command)? Because no software can work on the device if it cannot be accessed.

Comment: Ah, [an easy little search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[data-recovery]+boot+answers%3A1) turned up these: [How can I recover files from a phone that won't boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56940/16575) // [How to recover my files and personal data a phone who doesn't boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/85295/16575) // [How to backup data on a non-booting, unrooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/115116/16575) and more :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  Will take a look at those posts.  I haven't got my hands on the device yet (I am helping a friend), but I know it won't boot into recovery.  When I get it, I'll see if `adb` will recognize it.

Comment: OK, read all those posts.  Hard to know if the info provided is good because people on StackExchange don't do much upvoting (all the upvotes on the answers - with a single exception - are mine).  There is one possibility, but it will involve a lot of tinkering and experimentation, so am very open to recommendations for software that is known to just fix it.

Comment: As I've not had the case myself, I cannot tell by own experience, sorry. And as for upvoting: I usually only upvote if I can confirm, rarely just because it "looks good" :)